# How to retrieve data from Shared Preferences inside Presenter Class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am a newbie to MVP pattern for Android and Firebase Cloud Messaging. I have an application receiving FCM notifications sent from Firebase console.

In order to test the app, I have added a user to Firebase with email and Password authentication using FirebaseAuth. Email and FCM token are being saved to SharedPreferences and notifications are being received.

**Problem:** I now need to send an email from `SharedPreferences` and FCM token to my application server. I read a lot online about retrieving data from `SharedPreferences`and `Context`, but still, I can't put things together.

I am getting an error saying that the method `getInstance(this)` cannot be applied to `LoginPresenter.java`(check the code snippet below). I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong. Please folks, point me in the right direction.

```js
public class LoginPresenter implements LoginContract.Presenter, LoginInteractor.Callback {

@Override
    public void onAuthSuccess() {
        //Show notifications
        mLoginView.showPushNotifications();

        //Get master token before sending it to the server
       String savedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        //TODO:Check if token is not null.
        //Get user email
        final String savedEmail  = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUserEmail();
        saveTokenToServer(savedEmail, savedToken);
    }
```

I am using the following class for managing SharedPreferences:

```js
public class SharedPrefManager {
  private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "FCMSharedPref";
  private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "tagemail";

  private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
  private static Context mCtx;

  private SharedPrefManager(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
  }

  public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
      mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
  }

  //this method will save the email to shared preferences
  public boolean saveDeviceEmail(String email) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(TAG_EMAIL, email);
    editor.apply();
    return true;
  }

  //this method will fetch the device token from shared preferences
  public String getUserEmail() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(TAG_EMAIL, null);
  }

}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `this` is referring to your Presenter which has no `Context` that you can refer to with `this`, you have to pass the `Context` to your presenter or retrieve it from your `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

You are using SharedPrefs wrong. I cannot provide simpler answer than already provided in Android Developer's page:

- [Shared Prefs Explained](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Initializing SharedPrefs:

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Write to SharedPrefs:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.apply();
```

> To retrieve values from a shared preferences file, call methods such
>   as getInt() and getString(), providing the key for the value you want,
>   and optionally a default value to return if the key isn't present. For
>   example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

Comment: What is `preference_file_key` supposed to be? How to resolve this symbol?

Answer (score 0):

This is some sample code.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = MainActivity.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fileIncrementer = sharedPref.getInt("incrementor", 0);
fileIncrementer++;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("incrementor", fileIncrementer);
editor.commit();
```